# When can @IBOutlets be used?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Recently I am studying Swift to program for iOS and I came across a situation. Are @IBOutlet created only when the view appears on the user's screen?

Example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!
```

Comment: Hola João. Pode usar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ fazer as perguntas em língua português.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `UIViewController` an `IBOutlet` is only attached after `viewDidLoad()` is called.

Before this time the outlet is still nil.